# Get ACF values to email form - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

How do I get the values of Advanced Custom Fields and join it together in my email form when user submit it?

*I am trying to make a ticket booking/reservation but with selection from ACF values.*

**- I have a form that shows multiple ticket entries from ACF**

**- The user can select multiple tickets by increasing the quantity on the specific ticket**.

**- The selected tickets (Ticket Name, Price and Quantity) together with his information will be sent by email.**

Please image attached: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNS7Q.png)

To increase the quantity of the ticket to purchase, i have included an input form type number in the ticket loop.

The code below is working except on the field that is generated from Advanced Custom Form.

Mailer:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "myemail@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $ticket = $_POST[get_sub_field('ticket_type')];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $first_name ."Ticket" . $ticket . "\n" . $_POST['message'];  
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Buy Ticket</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
              if (have_rows('tickets')):
              while (have_rows('tickets')) : the_row();
            ?>
                <tr><td class="font-bold"> <i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i><?php the_sub_field('ticket_type'); ?></td>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><small><i><?php the_sub_field('ticket_description'); ?></i></small></td>
                    <td>Ticket Quantity:<input name="<?php the_sub_field('ticket_type'); ?>" class="form-control-sm m-r-10" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
                    </td>
                </tr>                
                <?php
                 endwhile;
                 else :
                 endif;
                ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
        Message <textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

The ticket is in a "Repeater" so it will generate more depending on the entries.

How can I include the user-selected ticket (name and price) with the its quantity on the email?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use the submitter's address as the from address; it's forgery and will cause bounces due to SPF failures. Use your own address as the from address; put the submitter in a reply-to. You tagged this question with PHPMailer, but you're not using PHPMailer.

Comment: THanks @Synchro! Noted! Any idea how to do add custom fields value inside email form? thanks!